# How to pass COM parameter of type SAFEARRAY** from C#

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, safearray

I'm trying to call a COM interface function from C# code.  This is an aggregated COM interface where I load the implementing COM interface by ProgID and I have to declare the interface myself.  The c++ function definition looks like:

```
STDMETHOD(VisualizeList) (HWND hWndParent, DWORD Options, SAFEARRAY **VialPositions, 
    SAFEARRAY **VialTypes, BSTR* TrayName) = 0;
```

The SAFEARRAYs contain strings and integers respectively and are used for both input and output.  I've tried defining the function in C# like this:

```
[PreserveSig]
int VisualizeList([In] IntPtr hwdParent,
    [In] uint Options, 
    [In, Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] ref String[] VialPositions,
    [In, Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_I4)] ref int[] VialTypes,
    [In, Out] ref String TrayName);
```

But when I attempt to call the interface function, it crashes.  I'm thinking its the SAFEARRAYs because everything else seems relatively straight forward.  I think I need one more order of referencing for the SAFEARRAYs, but I'm not sure how to do that.  So, how do you pass a parameter of type SAFEARRAY** from managed code?  I've scanned online and through other posts, but couldn't find anything that quite fit the bill.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: it could also depends on what you do on the C++ side.

Comment: Well, the C++ definition comes from a specification document.  I'm not creating the COM implementation, but I do have one that works and I can call it easily enough from c++ native code.  I could always make a wrapper for it using C++\CLI, but I was hoping to avoid having to do that.

Comment: What does the IDL declare?  What does the type library declare? I'd try declaring those parameters as [out] instead of [ref].  To start with, you could also see what making them generic Object's as [out] parameters would do.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no IDL for the interface. The COM servers are mostly implemented in MFC.  They usually define the interface in a c++ header and add it to their interface map.  So the COM interface isn't registered, you QueryInterface to get it from the servers.  Anyway, the root of the problem I think is the the SAFEARRAY**.  I think if it were just SAFEARRAY* it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: There may not be an IDL file, but you can reverse engineer one for the type library.  It has to have a type library.  Find out where the type library is (probably in the DLL) and use OleView which comes with Visual Studio to look at how the arguments are defined.